# How to make a smooth mesh

Tags: mesh

[image] Im making a twisted iron bar. I have added array modifier and with the help of empty i have twisted. After adding array modifier the edges been seen. How can i remove that edges of the array to look a continious mesh. After adding the sub division modifier the mesh look odd. How can i make a smooth mesh and plz suggest me is this method right or can i go with other method [image]

Comment: Couldn't you use a straight cylinder mesh and another using a screw modifier to add the twisted surface bars around it?

Comment: can u have a example for it plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atek, I try here to describe what you could do as an altenative.

1) I suppose you have 7 revolving bars around your cylinder, so in front view I add a 28 vertex simple circle, then I take a 2 vertex segment, duplicate and separate it. Then I extrude it along normal Z (press <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), here I extruded using 0.2 value.

Then I also added to the extruded "square" a screw modifier, with the settings below.

[image]

In the picture above I also extruded the original 28 vertex circle to get the cylinder: you can obviously smooth/subdivide/bevel the cylinder as you want to make it look "perfect". To smooth/subdivide/bevel the "bar", though, you could need "real geometry", so you could need to apply the screw modifier first.

2) then, to get the other "bars", set the pivot for rotating/scaling around the cursor, put the cursor at circle center, activate snapping to vertices, as you see below, then duplicate the first "bar", and rotate it around the circle centre, and snap it to the fourth vertices you have clockwise on the circle.

[image]

As you see in the picture, your "bar" is duplicated and fits nicely around the "cylinder".

3) to get all the bars, you need to repeat the "bar duplication" step other 5 times, to get this:

[image]

This is what I had in mind, I hope it is explained simply enough, and gives you another idea.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply i have done with ur method but the problem is the joint or the array finish and start of the new mesh between that there is edge seen. From a distance the edge cannot bee seen and when we zoom or near its seen there are section or copies. To the single mesh there are no edges. But when we add array modifier they are seen

Comment: I do not understand your comment above... there is no array at all in my method... and using subsurf modifier you can smooth the resulting mesh completely. Don't use arrays, use screw modifier and apply it, then you can also subsurf (with some edge creasing) and bevel, if you wish... the resulting mesh is completely smooth, no "joint" can be seen, because it's simpy not there (no arrays).

Comment: After making a mesh part i have used the array modifier to elongate. The basic or single mesh i have made with ur method but to elongate i have used the array. And how to elongate to make it long rod.

Comment: The best is to use screw modifier options to create a desired loop and iterate it as long as you wish. I would do that. More roughly, you can also duplicate the whole "base" shape and merge them along the bar axis Y, although some manual rotation on Y can be necessary, if the different revolving rods are not aligned...

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all faces that are going to be hidden by the Array modifier (selected on the screenshot, delete them on both sides of the object). Then enable the "merge" option in the modifier settings.

Normally, this is the way I'd be going for. Sadly, I can't tell you why the subsurf modifier messes up in this mesh. But if you put a fairly high Crease amount on most of the edges (except those that should be smoothed) it works fine.

If you are looking from your object from a distance, the Edge split modifier will do the trick. If you have some spare render time, go for a Subsurf and eventually then a Bevel modifier.

[image: screenshot]